Session management using HTML, CSS, and Javascript for frontend. Backend using node.js (express.js), Microsoft sql server


const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors'); 
const router = require('./router'); // Importing router module
const session = require('express-session');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

const app = express();
const port = 8000;

// Middleware
app.use(cors()); 
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(cookieParser()); 

app.use(session({
    secret:config.sessionSecret, 
    saveUninitialized : true, 
    resave : true}));


// Routes
app.use('/api', router); 

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'login.html'));
});

app.get('/home', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'home.html'));
});

app.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
    req.session.destroy((err) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).send('Error while logging out.');
        }
        res.redirect('/'); // Redirect to the first page after logout
    });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const XLSX = require('xlsx');
const sql = require('mssql');
const {poolPromise } = require('./dbconfig');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const path = require('path');

const router = express.Router();


router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    const { username, password } = req.body;

    try {
        const pool = await poolPromise;

        const result = await pool.request()
            .input('Username', sql.NVarChar, username)
            .query('SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username = @Username');

        if (result.recordset.length > 0) {
            const user = result.recordset[0];
            const passwordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.PasswordHash);

            if (passwordMatch) {
                // You can set up a session here or return user info/token
                res.status(200).json({ message: 'Login successful' });
            } else {
                res.status(401).json({ error: 'Invalid username or password' });
            }
        } else {
            res.status(401).json({ error: 'Invalid username or password' });
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error during login:', err);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'An internal error occurred. Please try again later.' });
    }
});

module.exports = router;
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Prime ASM Login Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="login.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="form-wrapper">
        <header class="image-container mb-4">
            <img src="prime_logo.jpeg" alt="Prime Logo" class="img-fluid">
        </header>
        <h2>Sign In</h2>
        <form id="Loginform">
            <div class="form-control">
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" required aria-label="Employee Username">
                <label for="username">Employee Username</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-control">
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required aria-label="Password">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
            </div>
            <button type="submit">Sign In</button>
            
            <p>
                Don't have an account? Feel free to <a href="register.html">Register</a>.
            </p>
            <div class="form-help"> 
                <div class="remember-me">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="remember-me">
                    <label for="remember-me">Remember me</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Message container for login status -->
            <div id="loginMessage" class="form-message"></div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script>
        document.getElementById('Loginform').addEventListener('submit', async function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            const formData = new FormData(this);
            const data = Object.fromEntries(formData);

            try {
                const response = await fetch('/api/login', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                    body: JSON.stringify(data)
                });

                if (response.ok) {
                    window.location.href = '/home';
                } else {
                    const result = await response.json();
                    document.getElementById('loginMessage').innerText = result.error || 'Login failed. Please check your username and password.';
                }
            } catch (err) {
                console.error('Error logging in:', err);
                document.getElementById('loginMessage').innerText = 'An error occurred. Please try again later.';
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>



Am failing to implement a secure authentication provided a user can go back to the login page without logging out. And i want the user to only access it after logging out or from the start run of the web application. The above code snippet is displaying the codes of my login page (Html, and Script), displays the codes of main application file, and it displays the route file
tried using the session-based redirection system

Please share the authentication method you are using along with the packages used in the project. A code snippet would help understand why you are facing the issue and if the code needs any tweaking.

Included a github link to my codes. Think that would be helpful than issuing you a small code snipet

Hi, welcome. A snippet will be more helpful; please read how to ask

Okay! Let me capture a snippet

Step 1: Setup the session from your snippet
app.use(session({
    secret: config.sessionSecret, 
    saveUninitialized: true, 
    resave: true,
    cookie: { secure: false } // In production, set this to true if using HTTPS
}));

Step 2: Set session on successful login.
Set the session when successfully logged in. in the /login route.
if (passwordMatch) {
   // You can set up a session here or return user info/token
   req.session.user = {
        username: username,
        role: 'admin',  // or any other user data you want to set
    };
   res.status(200).json({ message: 'Login successful' });
} else {
   res.status(401).json({ error: 'Invalid username or password' });
}

Step 3: Check for the session in the / route
If you have a session redirect the user to /home
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    if (req.session.user) {
        // User is already logged in, redirect to the dashboard
        return res.redirect('/home');
    }
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'login.html'));
});

If you don't have session you may want to redirect the user to the /login route from the /home page.
app.get('/home', (req, res) => {
    if (!req.session.user) {
        return res.redirect('/');
    }
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'home.html'));
});

Step 4 (Optional): Make reusable isAuthenticated middleware
You can make a middleware to check if user is logged in and if not logged in redirect the user.
function isAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.session.user) {
        // User is not logged in, redirect to the login route
        return res.redirect('/');
    }
    // If logged in, proceed to the next middleware/route handler
    next();
}

